# Animated SVG in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg

I need to play different animated SVG files in a UIView. For example, like [this](http://www.hypnobeast.com/spirals/Hypno_Beast_Spiral_1000x1000.svg).

Is it possible, and can anybody tell me how to do it?

**Update**

With [PocketSVG](https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG) I'm trying this (Thanks @Dhanashree):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGPathRef myPath = [PocketSVG pathFromSVGFileAtURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hypnobeast.com/spirals/Hypno_Beast_Spiral_1000x1000.svg"]];

    CAShapeLayer *myShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    myShapeLayer.path = myPath;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:myShapeLayer];   
}
```

But it doesn't work. The animated part of the SVG doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PocketSVG](https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG) will allow you to display and manipulate the lines of an SVG file.

```
PocketSVG *myBezier = [[PocketSVG alloc] initFromSVGFileNamed:@"BezierCurve1-iPad"];    
UIBezierPath *myPath = myBezier.bezier;

CAShapeLayer *myShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
myShapeLayer.path = myPath.CGPath;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:myShapeLayer];
```

Comment: I imported this framework, but showing "PocketSVG" undeclared.

Comment: can you help? pls check this